# "Function template has already been defined" with mutually exclusive `enable_if`s

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, type-traits, enable-if

MSVC produces error ("function template has already been defined") for the following code:

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible<T>::value>>
auto foo(T&& val) {
    return 0;
}

// note difference from above --->               !
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_default_constructible<T>::value>>
auto foo(T&& val) {
    return 0;
}
```

I thought it would work because there are mutually exclusive sfinae conditions. Can you help me with the hole in my understanding?

Comment: [`std::enable_if`'s doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) has a note section about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, their signature are the same; the default template arguments are not the part of the function template signature.

You can change them to

```
// the 2nd non-type template parameter are different
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible<T>::value>* = nullptr>
auto foo(T&& val) {
    return 0;
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_default_constructible<T>::value>* = nullptr>
auto foo(T&& val) {
    return 0;
}
```

Or

```
// the return type are different
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible<T>::value, int> foo(T&& val) {
    return 0;
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_default_constructible<T>::value, int> foo(T&& val) {
    return 0;
}
```